# Similar Excel Extensions as CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

This query is related to Mainframes & Excel. If we have to transfer a file from mainframes to excel and it is .CSV, then automatically excel delimits the contents with comma. I need to know how to automatically delimit the contents if delimiter present in the file is tilde '~'.

Is there any extension like CSV for tilde delimiter or any other delimiter? We have to delimit the contents manually if delimiter is anything else other than comma. Please advise. Thanks!!

Comment: Rename the file to .txt instead of .csv, the import wizard will allow you to specify a different delimiter.

Comment: Thanks Tyson. But we cannot use comma as a delimiter cause it can be part of the data being extracted. So, what would be the best possible delimiter to choose apart from comma, having an extension similar to CSV so that it can be automatically delimited??

Comment: Your question is unclear then.   It currently reads that you are attempting to import a .csv file from a mainframe into excel that uses a different delimiter than a comma, which can be done with excel.  It sounds like your real problem is getting the file generated with a different delimiter.  If that's the case, then this question has nothing to do with excel.

Comment: To be clear, excel can use any character as the delimiter.

Comment: I need to know the extension so that when the files aretransfreed they are automatically delimited. Here, delimiter used is not comma. So, my question is what extension to be given when using any other delimiter than comma, so that it can be automatically delimited in excel rather than manually doing it. It I give .txt, it will be transferred as a text file, not excel.

Comment: I know Tyson that excel can use any delimiter. That's why giving a unique delimiter '~'.

Comment: When you attempt to import a file into excel with the .txt extension there is a file import wizard that will let you select a delimiter to be used for the import.

Answer (score 2):

To import a CSV like file, specifically any delimited file, the file should be named with the .txt extension.  This will trigger a file import wizard.  In step 2 of 3 you will be able to specify the file is delimited and specify what character to be used as the delimiter, in your case ~.

Official Microsoft documentation is [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857).

Comment: Did this work out for you @hazel?